# "withoutString" help for something seems like unnecessary

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the "withoutString" practice in codingbat, i.e. removing a specific substring from the whole string. I did solve it actually, but now i forgot why did i add something (which is obviously needed) and can't figure out it now.

```
          public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
            int length = remove.length();
            String result = base;     //unnecesssary, but i sometimes get confused with these things
            int base_length = base.length();
            for(int i = 0; i < base_length-length+1; i++){ //Part i cannot understand is here(explanation below)
                if(result.toLowerCase().substring(i,length+i).equals(remove.toLowerCase())){
                   result = result.substring(0,i) + result.substring(length+i,base_length);
                   if(i+1 != base_length){ //in case that the needed substring is repeated one after another
                      i--;
                   }
                }
              base_length = result.length(); 
              }
              return result;
            }
```

Why "-length+1"is necessary, shouldn't it work without it either since i redefine base_length in the loop?

Exception i get for:

```
withoutString("Hello there", "llo") → "He there" (expected)
```

is this:

```
"Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9 (line number:7)"
```

(It works for things like withoutString("Hello there", "e") → "Hllo thr"(expected) by the way.)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `base.replace(remove,"")`?

Comment: Using .replace() is not allowed in our exams (At least for this one).

Comment: You should specify that in the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example `withoutString("Hello there", "llo")`, base.length = 11, length = 3. The last place you can compare will be the first e in there. After that, there are not enough characters left to match.

Comment: Oww,i saw it now. In comparing part, substring can't find enough character at the end of the string. Thanks!